# Не удаётся преобразовать строку в дату

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Нужно преобразовать строку (`string`) "Ноя 2018" в дату (`DateTime`). 
Делаю все внутри конструктора `Xamarin.Forms.ContetntPage`

Делаю так:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(a.finTermInfo, "MMM yyyy", new CultureInfo("ru-RU"));
```

где `a.finTermInfo` абсолютно точно является строкой (`string`) `"Ноя 2018"`

Однако бросает исключение

**System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**

Аналоги типа `Convert.ToDateTime(a.finTermInfo)` дают тотже результат.

Никак не могу понять в чем проблема.

В то же время в "соседнем" тестовом консольном приложении всё получается отлично без сучка и задоринки.

Comment: И кодировка одинаковая? И локаль совпадает?

Comment: @0andriy, да всё одинаковое, устанавливаю вручную, чтобы быть уверенным.

Comment: Культура должна быть `ru-RU` - с дефисом, а не подчёркиванием. Опечатка в вопросе или в реальном коде так?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Да, опечатка конечно.

Comment: Для приведенных данных и кода ошибка не воспроизводится